# Unity-iOS: Separating Unity iOS project into any existing iOS Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have developed Unity iOS project. I am using some 3ds max model files in it with some animation. When I create project through Unity, it does creating it automatically and installing it on the iPad. Now, I want to include this unity based functionality into my existing iOS project. How can i separate this unity project and integrate into my existing iOS Xcode project? I see lot of dependancies in Unity created project. I don't know the steps how can we separate this and integrate into any existing iOS Xcode project?

Please advise!

Comment: Note that there are many similar questions on here.  Be sure to search.

Comment: this is so hard to get right, it's not worth undertaking  :O

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we did it using Unity 5.2.2f1, Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1.

The steps outlined in the link below seem like a lot, but honestly, aside from the Import/Cleanup of some of the unity files, it takes < 5 min once you know the steps.

https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

Answer (score 0):

Actually thats not THAT hard to do. But honestly i would recommend not to try to integrate the generated project into your own, but start with the generated project and integrate yours. Since usually your part of the project will have a lot less changes in the build settings and dependencies.

Once you done the integration, you can update from a new export by simply copying the Classes and Libraries Folder from the generated project to the integrated one.

I explain how we integrated Unity into our iOS App in more detail here: http://www.markuszancolo.at/2014/05/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app

regards